# DriveApp.createFile causes a server error

Tags: google-apps-script

I got the following error when I tried to download a picture from a URL using Google Apps Script.

```
We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.
```

Here is the code.

```
function TT() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.dropbox.com/s/g9jtm390l67uqkb/128.png?dl=1');
  var blob = response.getBlob();
  Logger.log(blob.getContentType());
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, should try to create a file from its blob, not from the response it self.

```
function TT() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.dropbox.com/s/g9jtm390l67uqkb/128.png?dl=1');
  var blob = response.getBlob();

  Logger.log(blob.getContentType());

  var file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
}
```

I'v runned a test and it works perfectly.

Comment: Indeed, i tried today and i'v got that server error too, i think it's not something about the code... Something you can do is to put the "var file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);" inside a "try catch" statement for now.